# algorithmicx no listofalgorithms in contents section

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

I'm using [`algorithmicx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) to define some algorithms. It looks great, but I have one problem. When I use `\listofalgorithms` a page is created with the captions and links to the algorithms. However, there is no "List of algorithms" section in the contents section of the document. "List of tables" and "List of figures" are there just as expected.

Any ideas on why?

Comment: List of figures and tables usually *do not* show up in the table of contents. So you're probably using some package or class file that makes them appear there, it would be helpful if you tell us that bit of information.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom template made for the university called usthesis. It's in the Ubuntu repositories. I'm replicating the table and figure snippets of code in the .sty and .cls file for algorithm. But no luck so far. Will keep at it.

Answer (score 16):

You can manually add the list of algorithms to the table of contents using the `\addcontentsline` command.  Immediately after `\listofalgorithms` in your code, include

> `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of algorithms}`

(and make sure to compile it a couple of times until the output stops changing).  By changing `section` in that command to `chapter`, `subsection`, etc., you can affect what level it displays at in the table of contents (i.e. how big it is, whether it's bold, if it's indented below another higher item).